# How to get a Spring web service to log to the JBoss server log

Tags: java, jboss, log4j, spring-ws

I have working Spring web service, but I get no logging information from it in the JBoss logs.

There is no log4j.properties within the application, as I believe that would override the standard behaviour of hooking in to the JBoss logs.

I've tried creating categories in the jboss-log4j.xml for everything I can think of with no luck.

The default JBoss logging threshold level is set to DEBUG.

Specifically I would like to get the soap request/responses but as I say above, at this point I get no log output from the application at all.

There are a couple of system.out.println log statements that do show but obviously I don't want to swap my logging for system.out.

Does anyone have any idea what is wrong?

If it helps I do have

```
 <property name="interceptors">
            <bean class="org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.interceptor.PayloadLoggingInterceptor"/>
        </property>
```

Declared as part of my org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.mapping.PayloadRootQNameEndpointMapping bean

Edit:
Some of the categories I have tried.

```
<category name="org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.interceptor.PayloadLoggingInterceptor">
    <priority value="TRACE" />
</category>
<category name="org.springframework.ws.soap.endpoint.interceptor.PayloadLoggingInterceptor">
    <priority value="TRACE" />
</category> 
<category name="org.springframework.ws.server.MessageTracing.sent">
    <priority value="TRACE" />
</category>
<category name="com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap">
    <priority value="DEBUG" />
</category>
```

Comment: @jddsantaella a good point, if I send a malformed request in I do see errors thrown by com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.EnvelopeFactory however those are written out to STDERR

Comment: That is good. Review Root Category debug level and set it to TRACE. I think that by default its level is INFO, but I am no sure.

Comment: I'm not a JBoss geek, but I believe you must have an application specific log config file, if not, your application won't log anything to it's appender (a console appender is proper), and JBoss can't sense your logs.

Answer (score 0):

Without having the entire logfile its really hard to know what your logger config is but here are a few suggestions

1. Make sure the log level is set appropriately on the root logger as it overrides / the other thresholds.
2. Create a new appender for your logs that can have its own log threshold as well as a different log file (might be helpful in some cases).
3. Refer http://docs.jboss.org/process-guide/en/html/logging.html for more details.

> ```
> <root>
>     <priority value="DEBUG"/>
>     <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE"/>
>     <appender-ref ref="FILE"/>
> </root>
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Be sure you have your logging libraries correctly defined, for example, just try to include this dependencies in your project so that you have your log messages linked against log4j and remove any other dependency you have with any logging library. With this change it should work.

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.1</version>
</dependency>
```